# Asus memo pad 8 led notification

Tags: tablet, notification-led, proximity-sensor

Hi there I have an ASUS MeMO Pad 8 ME181C I want to know is there a proximity sensor or a notification led on right hand side of the tablet.
If it's a notification led how does it work? 
Thanks...